# How to keep the center of a JComponent at the same spot when resizing it?

Tags: java, graphics

I have program that resizes a button.
I just want to keep the center point in the center.
Perhaps by moving it by the distance between the center and…the upper left corner
Like when I resize the box in JSwing.
I want the center point to remain in the same spot.
How can I change the x, y of the upper left coordinates as the box increases
while keeping the center point in the same spot?
What woulf be the steps to get this done?
I guess my using the distance between the center and the upper left corner but how would that help
https://pastebin.com/0r8Vhez7
here's the code for context.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Buttons
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         //Buttons.JLabelExperiments JE = new Buttons().new JLabelExperiments();
         //JE.ASY();
         Buttons.JButtonExperiments JEB = new Buttons().new JButtonExperiments();
         JEB.Print();
    }

    class JLabelExperiments
    {
        public static void ASY()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(1200, 1200);
            JLabel lol = new JLabel(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
            lol.setBounds(500, 400, 380, 200);
            lol.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            frame.add(lol);
            JSlider J = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 200, 0);
            J.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
            J.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
            J.setPaintLabels(true);
            J.setPaintTicks(true);
            J.setPaintTrack(true);
            J.addChangeListener(e ->
            {
                {
                    lol.setHorizontalAlignment(J.getValue());
                    JLabel LOL = new JLabel(String.valueOf(J.getValue()));
                    LOL.setBounds(700, 700, 100, 150);
                    frame.add(LOL);
                }
            });
            frame.add(J);
            JSlider j = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, 0);
            j.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
            j.setMinorTickSpacing(2);
            j.setPaintTrack(true);
            j.setPaintTicks(true);
            j.setPaintLabels(true);
            j.setBounds(200, 700, 400, 100);
            j.addChangeListener(e ->
            {
                      lol.setVerticalAlignment(j.getValue());
                      JLabel HUH = new JLabel(String.valueOf(j.getValue()));
                      HUH.setBounds(950, 700, 100, 150);
                      frame.add(HUH);
            });
            System.out.printf("%1$s,    %2$s", J.getChangeListeners(), j.getChangeListeners());
            frame.add(j);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void asy()
        {

        }
    }

    class JButtonExperiments
    {
        public static void Print()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(1200, 1200);
            JButton B = new JButton("w");
            B.setBounds(600, 600, 160, 160);
            B.setText(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
            frame.add(B);
            JSlider width = new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0, 0, 100);
            JSlider height = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 0, 100);
            width.setLocation(200, 600);
            JLabel widthBox = new JLabel("Width");
            widthBox.setBounds(20, 500, 120, 120);
            height.setLocation(1000, 600);
            JLabel heightBox = new JLabel("Height");
            heightBox.setBounds(1180, 500, 120, 120);
            width.setSize(100, 600);
            height.setSize(100, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
            B.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    counter.getAndIncrement();
                    if(counter.get() == 1)
                    {
                        frame.add(width, height);
                    }
                    if(counter.get() == 3)
                    {
                         width.addChangeListener(E ->
                         {
                               B.setSize(B.getWidth()+width.getValue(), B.getHeight());
                         }
                         );

                        height.addChangeListener(E ->
                        {
                              B.setSize(B.getWidth(), B.getHeight()+height.getValue());
                        }
                        );
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This was just a practice project but it seems this information may be more useful so please before forgive any lack of readability.

This code when run will make a button if you click it twice it will activate sliders that allow you to change the width and height of the button. By adding the value of the sliders to the value of the Button's width and height.

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything in swing, but I think you could use a gridbaglayout for this. And if you run out of ideas and nothing works, you could potentially try subclassing an existing LayoutManager and adding custom code to achieve what you've mentioned here

Comment: `B.setText(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());` ... Why? I've wasted a good 5 minutes trying to figure out why your code won't do anything only to bump my head against this.  As ControlAltDel said - use an appropriate layout manager, it will do it for you for free

Comment: `JSlider width = new JSlider(SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0, 0, 100);` also causes a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid range properties`, you might want to read the JavaDocs to figure out why

Comment: Uhh how can I used layout manager to move the center point of a component while simultanustly resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Use an appropriate layout manager, get it for free...

Now your button is always in the middle...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50)));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Button in the middle");
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.ipadx = 100;
            gbc.ipady = 100;
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

    }
}
```

Change the text and see what happens ... for free

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Check my comment in the question...